# PCF CLI start and restart

Tags: cloud-foundry

I see there are two commands in Pivotal cloud foundry: `cf start` and `cf restart`.

What are the differences between these commands and the right scenarios to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is the name:

`cf start` - starts a stopped application.  If the application is already started then it does nothing.

`cf restart` - stops all instances of a running application and starts it again.  If the application is stopped, it simply starts it.